# Visual Studio 2015 Android Project Multithreaded Compilation

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015 there is opportunity to create android c++ project (static library, for example). 
Is there way to enable multithreaded compilation in VS2015 android project?

I need feature similar to "ndk-build -j8", but for VS2015 android project.

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of is changing the configuration type to "Makefile".
But you need to have all the necessary configurations and make file properly setup

[image]

Then you can add the command line parameter in NMake section of property pages :

[image]